# Two column layout - one column with min width

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a two column layout whereby one of the columns has a min-width value? Please see the code below:

```
#container {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 1200px;
   min-width: 960px;
   height: 600px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#sidebar {
   float: left;
   width: 20%;
   min-width: 300px;
   height: 100%;
}

#content {
   float: left;
   width: 80%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that when the window is resized and `#sidebar` gets the min-width value applied, `#content` will drop off the page.

Ideally I would like to do this without having to use `display: table` and ideally a CSS only solution would be preferred.

EDIT: Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/2DwB3/

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem as `min-width` is overriding the `width` property all the time. because the container has an explicit width and `20%` of `960px` is less than `300px`

Comment: Apologies - I've updated the value. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot have min-width: 300px as the other column takes up 80%. 960 - 960x(80/100) = 192px

Comment: No worries. But please that as long as the container has a fixed width value, one of these two properties (`width` or `min-width`) will override the other one. I.e. the sidebar will have always the same width.

Comment: Apologies again - please see the latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmwIo

```
  #container {
     width: 960px;
     height: 600px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     overflow: hidden;
  }

  #sidebar {
     float: left;
     min-width: 300px;
     height: 100%;
  }

  #content {
  }
```

Comment: That won't work for me as I need to put stuff in `#content' that needs to be floated and inherit the correct width from the parent, etc.

Comment: That is what it does.

Comment: Here a solution to have a left column with 100% height as a faux column http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fkAei

Answer (score 0):

The `#content` column is collapsing (even in full screen size) because `min-width` value of the *left* column (`#sidebar`) exceeds its `width` value, Hence the remaining space for the *right* column (`#content`) is less than `80%` of the width of the `#container`.

In this case the width of the `#content` should be changed base on the width of the `#sidebar`. But as you have used `min-width` property for the sidebar, if you set a lower value than the width value *(something like `150px`)*, It'll be impossible to calculate the width of the `#content` even by using CSS3 [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function.

Alternatively, you can stop floating the right column and hide the extra horizontal overflow by [`overflow-x: hidden;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) to achieve the desired goal:

```css
#sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 80%; /* Changed for the demo */
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pasas/2/edit)**.